# Idea: larger text box for typing questions on desktop

Tags: feature-request, questions, design, markdown

I am primarily a stackoverflow user. My questions and responses are often long and detailed. However, I always find myself increasing the height of the text box and looking for ways to increase the width as well.

When adding code and other elements to my questions, I find myself scrolling back and forth (especially at the preview section) losing myself in the text, because I'm unable to see the overall picture of what I'm writing. Expanding the length of the box helps. But it would be easier if it were like that immediately to start with OR if we could add preferences to how we want it to look like when we type our questions/answer. A pop-up option for a text box for the desktop version would be useful so we can see the overall picture of what's going on.

Code formatting in the text box is also tedious. Considering we have to make 4 indented spaces to markup code, my comments in the code or some lines of code look sloppy (while typing) and confuse me as to whether a newline has started or if I need to indent again? Then, again, I find myself going to the preview section to make sure that it looks decent and it makes sense. I'm sure this happens to other users when adding math formulas, long quotes, etc.

I do understand the logic of the width of the text box. There are MANY advantages. For example, seeing the "Similar Questions" section on the right or on the top of the question. This is EXTREMELY beneficial.

However, it would be nice if we could have an extended width + length + the Similar questions sections on both the top of the question and below the question.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: concerning formatting (since you mentioned code format): you can mark a selection and indent it as code by pressing Ctrl + K. There's also some other shortcuts. Additionally all formatting options are available in the editor's toolbar. In addition to that (while I agree on the height part) the width gives me an idea of how much it will look like on screen without having to check the preview.

Comment: I didn't know about that shortcut actually. Thanks! What bothers me mostly  about the width is actually that it doesn't help me with the preview. For some reason the text and font when typing is different, and the format of the paragraph is also different, that's what mainly confuses me and throws me off, width wise...

Comment: Shameless plugs: http://stackapps.com/questions/3894/dude-wheres-my-cursor and http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts.

Comment: A good idea might be to just disable line wrapping in the editor input.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah I feel like this feature would be super useful, I am trying to format a long '2-dimensional' array in one of the question I am creating at the moment, and the text wrapping is so annoying:

[image]

I mean, it's wrapping before teh preview space does, which I find very frustrating.